# mysql questions for beginners

Tags: command-line, server, mysql

ok, I have a few questions regarding mysql.
I am currently running ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS command line version.

I am looking for a database that I can use.  I am confused at this point because I am uninformed.

mysql is just one database that is on the server? or can it contain several or many databases

What programs do I use to access it on the server or is it a vt-100 type access?

I understand that mysql comes with lamp? or ubuntu.  I am thinking that it is already installed but not sure how to access it, but that is another question for later.

Outside of the man pages and the ubuntu manual, is there a site for its setup and use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Outside of the man pages and the ubuntu manual, is there a site for its setup and use?

This [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html)  will show you how to install and configure MySQL server using CLI.

> mysql is just one database that is on the server? or can it contain
>   several or many databases

MySQL is a Database Server and not a database.

MySQL is only one of the DB server and there are others such as PostgreSQL, Oracle, Derby, etc...

You can create multiple DBs using MySQL server.

> I understand that mysql comes with lamp? or ubuntu. I am thinking that
>   it is already installed but not sure how to access it, but that is
>   another question for later

No it does not come with Ubuntu by default. Some LAMP packages such as [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) come with MySQL.

Comment: ok, I need more info because this has produced more questions.  A database server is a DB environment? and a database is where the data resides?  I used to program in dbase III and have used MS access.  I am a mac guy now.  SO I still need to use/install a database that we can access, add to, share correct?  One friend recommended grok, but that left me spinning more. I am looking for a centralized db that multiple operating systems can use. I appreciate your time and help you guys.

Comment: @ankhseeker Yes. A database is a complex system that stores data in a specific format. This specific format / feature is defined by each DB Server. So each DB Server provides its own method to access - read / write to the database. If you are looking for a multi platform DB, then mysql is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

To actually install mysql, you would also need to type in:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

As mentioned by Kenpachi, mysql-server does not come installed with Ubuntu upon its installation. I figured I would relay this in there if you are not aware on how to get mysql server on there.

Answer (score 1):

I would first start by reading a little bit about databases before you actually start working with them, or at least have a book next to you as a reference. There are several places on the internet where you can download free ebooks about MySQL to get up to speed :)

Generally speaking, mysql(-server) is an environment that can hold different databases. By default, it only has a little bit of data in a few databases that are required to work correctly and besides the users that are necessary for access rights, you're rarely going to access the existing databases. You can create your own database for example by

```
$mysql -u root -p    // to log in your database environment as 'root'
mysql> CREATE DATABASE people;
mysql> USE people;
mysql> CREATE TABLE names (
       `    id int(4) unsigned not null primary key,
       `    name varchar(32) not null
       `    );
```

With that, you have a new empty database with 1 table that stores names.
Every database can have multiple tables, and ever table can have multiple columns and every column can have multiple values, links, binaries, etc.

To see what you are doing when you're learning, I advise you to install phpmyadmin, which is a web-based front-end for your database. You can easily create databases and see what is going on. It will also give you the queries (mysql strings) that are used for the operations you perform. After installation, just browse to `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` and it'll be a lot easier for you to see what you're doing. You'll also be able to create databases without having to know everything about MySQL.

LAMP is an abreviation for (L)inux(A)pache(M)ySQL(P)HP, which are 4 different environments that are frequently used together to create dynamic websites. This is a bit of a time of change, as many web hosters are currently switching to Nginx instead of Apache, and MariaDB instead of MySQL. Only in later stages of development, you will start to see any differences between them. They're all there with the same purpose. But if you already have MySQL installed on Linux, you already have half of the LAMP stack installed.
You can always install the rest manually with apt.

Comment: Wow!  You people are terrific!  the light bulb just went on upstairs!  Thanks.  Jakke, Your code example above looks very readable.  I will get a book and check it out now.  I do have LAMP installed btw.  kenpachi, thanks you for taking the time to comment.  I appreciate them all! I will see if apt-get will find/install phpmyadmin.